# In WebRTC, can ICE candidates be re-used across different RTCPeerConnections?

Tags: webrtc

I am working on setting up group calls involving up to 8 peers using WebRTC.

Let's say a peer needs to set up 7 RTCPeerConnections to join a group call. Instead of relying on `onicecandidate` event for every single RTCPeerConnection, I was wondering if I can track the client's `icecandidates` in a central location and reuse it for each new RTCPeerConnection. (e.g. Signaling Server will keep track of a peer's full ICE candidates, and share them with other peers as soon as they need them).

I am unsure what the average number of 'icecandidates' each client will have, but with ice trickle process, it seems that many duplicate http or websocket calls will need to be made to a Signaling Server in oder to exchange ice candidates between any 2 peers.

So I was wondering if I could just "accumulate" ice candidates locally and reuse them when new RTCPeerConnection will need to be made with new peer.

Comment: Thanks for your question. I'm in the exact same situation; thinking of storing the ICE candidates in my database, the time the user joins the call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not. ICE candidates are associated with the peerconnection and its ice username fragment and password.
There is a feature called ice forking that would allow what you ask for but it is not implemented yet. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=11252#c3 has some details.

Comment: Thanks, I had a hunch that this would be the case. What is your source for believing so?